# Character Encoding error with Groupme bot using Groupy library

Tags: python, unicode, bots, python-unicode, groupme

I am trying to get started writing a Groupme bot using [Groupy](https://groupy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

There have been a few related posts to this one, but they seemed a bit more technically challenging of issues, the solutions didn't seem efficient, and none of them solved the issues I'm having.

**Here is the code I have so far:**

```
import groupy

token = "{My Token}"

from groupy.client import Client
client = Client.from_token(token)

groups = list(client.groups.list_all())

for group in groups:
    print(group)
```

Firstly, I don't believe this is related but, in eclipse it is giving a warning that groupy is an unused import, even though it seems to me that that is not so.

More importantly, the strange part about the issues I'm having is that the error messages change without any edits to the above code.

Here is an error message that I've gotten:
**In each of these error messages, I've edited the beginning of the file locations... because I'm paranoid**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Projects\Eclipse\eclipse-workspace\Gort's Cousin\groupme_bot.py", line 15, in <module>
   <Group(name='One of my group's names')>
   <Group(name='Another one of my group's names')>
    print(group.name)
  File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 27-28: character maps to <undefined>
```

So, this time the system actually returns a couple groups I am in. But then calls an exception because of a unicode error of sorts.

Without changing any code, I also get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\groupy\session.py", line 49, in data
    return self.json()['response']
  File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 808, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 60865 (char 60864)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Eclipse\eclipse-workspace\Gort's Cousin\groupme_bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    groups = list(client.groups.list_all())
  File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\groupy\pagers.py", line 61, in autopage
    self.items = self.fetch_next()
  File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\groupy\pagers.py", line 51, in fetch_next
    return self.fetch()
  File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\groupy\pagers.py", line 42, in fetch
    return self.endpoint(**self.params)
  File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\groupy\api\groups.py", line 21, in _raw_list
    return [Group(self, **group) for group in response.data]
  File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\groupy\session.py", line 51, in data
    raise exceptions.InvalidJsonError(self._resp) from e
groupy.exceptions.InvalidJsonError: The JSON was incomplete/invalid
```

I am most likely incorrect, but it seems to me that there is some issue with the way groupy is aggregating the groups, and/or how I've set up my project to handle those calls.

Any help with this issue would be awesome.

I can also add some code from the groupy library if that becomes necessary.

**TLDR: Getting a "UnicodeEncodeError" error using Groupy to write a groupme bot in Python**

Answer (score 2):

Solved: 
It was an issue where group names with emojis were not playing nice with the Cp1252 encoding I have as a global setting in eclipse. I changed the run configuration of the file to encode to UTF-16BE. The emojis don't print correctly to the console, but all of the groups are printed with no errors.